# Only keep levels that are incomplete, based on two columns

Tags: r, na, delete-row

I could really use some help with the following:

I some sample data:

```
Group<-c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D", "D")
Value1<-c("7","1",8,7,"NA",9,10,12)
Value2<-c("NA","NA","NA",7,3,9,7,4)
df<-data.frame(Group, Value1, Value2)

  Group Value1 Value2
     A      7     NA
     A      1     NA
     B      8     NA
     B      7      7
     C     NA      3
     C      9      9
     D     10      7
     D     12      4
```

I want delete all groups that are either fully filled in for Value1 and Value2 (like Group D) or have no data for Value2 within a group (like Group A). So that I end up with the groups that are filled in for both Value1 and Value2 but are incomplete, like:

```
  Group Value1 Value2
     B      8     NA
     B      7      7
     C     NA      3
     C      9      9
```

I Know how to delete NA's, and I have tried some things with

```
setDT()[,  := if(any(Value2==)) "" else "" , by = .()]
```

but I don't really now how to use it in this case..

Does someone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[!all(is.na(Value2)) & (anyNA(Value1) | anyNA(Value2))], Group]
```

Output:

```
   Group Value1 Value2
1:     B      8     NA
2:     B      7      7
3:     C   <NA>      3
4:     C      9      9
```

Note that in order for this to work, your values should indeed be `NA` and not just `"NA"` as strings, i.e. it works with a modified dataframe example:

```
Group<-c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D", "D")
Value1<-c("7","1",8,7,NA,9,10,12)
Value2<-c(NA,NA,NA,7,3,9,7,4)
df<-data.frame(Group, Value1, Value2)
```

Comment: also possible as `tidyverse`: `library(tidyverse);
df %>% 
  mutate_at(-1,~ifelse(. == "NA", NA, .)) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(!all(is.na(Value2)) & (anyNA(Value1) | anyNA(Value2)))`

Comment: Also, the first two 'Value1' numbers are string instead of integers, which makes the columns factors instead of integers.

Comment: @arg0naut & Jimbou Thank you! Works both perfectly! wl1234 & arg0naut Thank you for the notice I wasn't sure how to create the integer with NA data so I did it like this. In the real data the value columns are all integer

Answer (score 2):

Using data from @arg0naut (to keep `NA` as `NA` and not "NA") a base R solution using two `ave` would be

```
df[!with(df, ave(complete.cases(df), Group, FUN = all) | 
             ave(is.na(Value2), Group, FUN = all)), ]

#  Group Value1 Value2
#3     B      8     NA
#4     B      7      7
#5     C     NA      3
#6     C      9      9
```

We keep two conditions separately and find the rows which we don't want to select and then take negation of it.